# How to make a direct link, so it resets the whole path in React-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have this kind of `Router` and what I found as a side effect is that when I'm for example in some `localhost:3000/tododetails/some_id` and I click the link for example: `Notes Form`, it doesn't direct me to `localhost:3000/notesform` but it does direct to `localhost:3000/tododetails/notesform` which is obviously not defined.
How am I able to edit it to work correctly? Tried to make an absolute path inside `Link`, like this: `localhost:3000/notesform`, but as result it is `localhost:3000/tododetails/localhost:3000/notesform` which is even worse than before.

My router:

```
<BrowserRouter>
          <ul>
              <li><Link to="todolist">Todo List</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="todoform">Todo Form</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="noteslist">Notes List</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="notesform">Notes Form</Link></li>
          </ul>

          <Route exact path="/todolist" component={TodoList} />
          <Route exact path="/todoform" component={TodoForm} />
          <Route exact path="/todoform/:id" component={TodoForm} />
          <Route exact path="/tododetails/:id" component={TodoDetails} />

          <Route exact path="/noteslist" component={NotesList} />
          <Route exact path="/notesform" component={NotesForm} />
          <Route exact path="/notesform/:id" component={NotesForm} />
          <Route exact path="/notesdetails/:id" component={NotesDetails} />
      </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: I think you missing backslash in your link: `<li><Link to="/noteslist">Notes List</Link></li>"` can you try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must start your link value with a `/` as follow:

```
<li><Link to="/todolist">Todo List</Link></li>
<li><Link to="/todoform">Todo Form</Link></li>
<li><Link to="/noteslist">Notes List</Link></li>
<li><Link to="/notesform">Notes Form</Link></li>
```

Otherwise, it is considered as a relative link.